# Powershell Having a global variable for a changing filepath

Tags: powershell

This is only the second script I've ever written so try and bear with me

I have four sets of customer files that I need to rename using separate counters and move to a couple of locations. Ideally, I'd like the counter variable to be global, based on the source & folder path, instead every time I'm looking for the files per literal path. The issue is that if I put the counter path in the global variables section, something like

```
$_counter = $_source+"merge.tokens\"+$_folder+"_counter"
```

This is static and so gives the same rolling counter to each customer (from the first customers counter), even if i put it in each section. I want it to be dynamic based on the $_folder variable, thus giving each customer export its own unique number based on the number of files it exports. This is my code as it stands currently;

```
##Global variables
#Global source for files
$_source = "C:\exports\"
#FTP path for group1 files
$_group1 = "\\FTP\exports\group1\"
#FTP path for group2
$_group2 = "\\FTP\exports\group2\"
#extension type that needs to move from source path
$_FileType= @("*.xml")


##Customer1_export##
#path for the customer1 files
$_Folder = "customer1_Export"
#set the counter name for the rename
$_counter = $_source+"merge.tokens\customer1_Export_counter"
#Get counter for this folder
[int]$_i = Get-Content $_counter
#Rename all the files as per counter
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name –replace '\d+', $script:_i++} 
#Move them to the designated FTP folder
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
move-Item -Destination ($_group1)
#Save the new counter value
$_i | out-file $_counter -Force

##Customer2_export##
#path for the customer2 files
$_Folder = "customer2_Export"
#set the counter name for the rename
$_counter = $_source+"merge.tokens\customer2_Export_counter"
#Get counter for this folder
[int]$_i = Get-Content $_counter
#Rename all the files as per counter
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name –replace '\d+', $script:_i++} 
#Move them to the designated FTP folder
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
move-Item -Destination ($_group2) 
#Save the new counter value
$_i | out-file $_counter -Force

##customer3_export##
#path for the customer3 files
$_Folder = "customer3_Export"
#set the counter name for the rename
$_counter = $_source+"merge.tokens\customer3_Export_counter"
#Get counter for this folder
[int]$_i = Get-Content $_counter
#Rename all the files as per counter
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name –replace '\d+', $script:_i++} 
#Move them to the designated FTP folder
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
move-Item -Destination ($_group2) 
#Save the new counter value
$_i | out-file $_counter -Force

##customer4_Export##
#path for the customer4 files
$_Folder = "customer4_Export"
#set the counter name for the rename
$_counter = $_source+"merge.tokens\customer4_Export_counter"
#Get counter for this folder
[int]$_i = Get-Content $_counter
#Rename all the files as per counter
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name –replace '\d+', $script:_i++} 
#Move them to the designated FTP folder
GCI -recurse (($_source)+($_folder)) -include ($_FileType) | `
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | `
move-Item -Destination ($_group2) 
#Save the new counter value
$_i | out-file $_counter -Force
```

Thanks in advance for any answers and suggestions for tidying up the code.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'd highly recommend you avoid naming your variables with an underscore prefix: `$_counter`, etc.  The name `$_` is used by PowerShell as the pipeline variable (which you actually use: `$_.CreationTime`) and could lead to confusion for anyone reading your code.

Comment: I'd refactor your logic into a function if it's the same for each customer, then you can just make the counter a local variable within the function. If you call the function once per customer they'll each get their own counter...

Comment: `$_Counter` seemss to be referenced as a filename, i.e. `Get-Content $_counter` that contains a single integer as text! Is that your intention?

Comment: Thanks all. I'll have to look at functions, but i've only just started with Powershell, so couldn't quite grasp the concept yet.